# Load local HTML from file

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, jsx

I'm new in React Native and I try to load local .html file in WebView but unfortunately app crash without any log in console.

My code is very simple:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, Dimensions, WebView} from 'react-native';

class HTMLLoader extends Component {
  render() {
    const PolicyHTML = require('./text.html');

    var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

    return (
        <WebView
          source={{html: PolicyHTML}}
          style={{width: width, height: height}}
       />
    );
  }
}

export default class IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
            <HTMLLoader/>
    );
  }
}

// skip these lines if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
  'AwesomeProject',
  () => IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe);
```

this is content of .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

any hint will be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer for my question, updated `return` has been posted below:

```
return (
    <WebView
      source={PolicyHTML} // object should be assigned directly to the WebView source property
      style={{width: width, height: height}}
   />
);
```